# Twisted LoopingCall serialized when needed

Tags: python, twisted

I am using a LoopingCall to get jobs to a worker every X seconds - but there might be times when the worker doesn't finish the previous job sooner that X seconds and then I want the LoopingCall to not get any new job. Basically I want a way to let the LoopingCall to wait another round until it pulls the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html

The function your `LoopingCall` calls may return a deferred. Rescheduling will not occur until that deferred is fired.

I'm having trouble understanding your post, but I think this is what you're after. Have your worker-function return a deferred to the LoopingCall and fire it when the job is complete.

Comment: After implementing the code with your answer, I can definitely say that this is what I wanted :)